# Why does Google Play prevents installing app on tablet without GPS?

Tags: android, android-permissions

When I try to install the app on the device, Google Play says

> "Your device is not compatible with this version"

[image]

**EDIT:** For info, the tablet has a front camera, but no back camera. Could it be related to the problem ?

The app needs `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permissions for BLE discovery, but should work without GPS, hence the line

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
    android:required="false" />
```

App manifest file is below

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.microphone"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
    android:required="false" />

<permission
    android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<!-- Normal permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<!-- Dangerous permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

Comment: Could it be your Android version rather than some feature? Check your `android:minSdkVersion`. It's also possible that some (third-party) library you are using is adding stuff to the manifest, so it's best to check the final manifest as embedded in the APK.

Comment: minSdkVersion is 16 and tablet is on SDK 28. I check the embedded manifest version

Comment: I would rip-off all them bunch of additional required permissions on the manifest just to certify myself it is a gps question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding the following lines to the app manifest file:

```
<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />


<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location"
        android:required="false" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add

```
<supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

to the root of manifest file

Comment: I'm trying to deploy an APK in beta version with your solution, but now Google console says "framework version not compatible, you are about to reduce the number of compatible devices, 
safe: "16 or later version""